# Update Folder Count on cascade delete in Laravel via eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have 3 tables:

1. Tasks
2. Folders
3. Folder tasks

**Tasks** table will have all `task_name`, **Folder** table will have `folder_name`, `task_count` and **Folder Tasks** is a pivot table which will store `folder_id` and `task_id`.

All tables have many-to-many relationships.

I added cascade delete tasks. So, if i delete a task then it will deleted everywhere including pivot table. I'm deleting tasks using eloquent delete. This is working fine

But, I need to update the count of tasks of each folder in **Folders** table once I delete a task.

As a task can be stored in multiple folders, it's hard to update the count of all folder's `task_count` on cascade deleted tasks. I'm stuck here.

How can i update all `task_count`'s of affected folders?

Comment: What did you try so far? What is looking like your method that delete your items?

Comment: I tried to get all folders which has the domain and then i tried to update all the return folders domain_count but this is not the right way if i have large set of folders to update. So, looking for better solution.

I tried below query to get all the folders containing that domain.

`$task_table = Tasks::find($task_id);`
`$task_table->folders()->wherePivot('task_id','=',$task_id)->get()`

Comment: What is looking like your method that delete your items?

Comment: Here is the code for deleting task: `Tasks::where('id', $task_id)->delete();` . This will delete that particular task everywhere including folders containing this task.

Comment: "*including folders containing this task*" - Associated folders are deleted? I don't fully understand, I thought that concerned folders needed to be updated? Or was you talking about the pivot table?

Comment: I meant that task will be deleted from all folders which has that task. Folders won't be deleted. I just need a solution to update the `task_count` of each affected folder once a particular task is deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the mysql trigger. Here is the example.

```
USE `test`;
DELIMITER 
$$
CREATE TRIGGER `tasks_ADEL` 
AFTER DELETE ON tasks FOR EACH ROW
-- Edit trigger body code below this line. Do not edit lines above this one
BEGIN
   update folder as f right join folder_tasks as ft on f.id = ft.folder_id set task_count = task_count + 1 where ft.task_id = OLD.id
END;
$$
```

Here you can find the uses example https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/mysql-triggers.php#MTAD

Comment: Ok but how can i do that in laravel eloquent?

Comment: Just you can run this with mysql database..or you can create a migration for this..it will be automatically do rest of the things.

Comment: Triggers used to perform an action on any database transaction will be happend on db table associated... before the transaction or after the transaction. the geiven example for the After task deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i found a way to update `tasks_count` myself. It  may not be the efficient way but solves the issue.

```
$task = Tasks::find($domain_id);
$folders = $task->folders->pluck('pivot.folder_id');
Tasks::where('user_id', $user_id)->where('id', $domain_id)->delete();
foreach($folders as $key => $value){
    $folder_table = Folder::find($value);
    $folder_table->tasks_count = $folder_table->tasks()->count();
    $folder_table->save();
}
```